# "Преступник стал жертвой правосудия"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Есть ли ошибка в предложении "Преступник стал жертвой правосудия"?

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что есть. И очень грубая, не только стилистическая, но и смысловая. 
Такая фраза возможна как ироничная - и только в этом случае.

Иначе имеет место лексическая несочетаемость, причем довольно хитрая. Попарно - возможно, но все три слова ("преступник", "жертва" и "правосудие") обьединить никак не получается.
"Жертвой правосудия" может стать невиновный (правда правосудие в этом случае правильнее будет назвать кривосудием), преступник может быть жертвой, но никак не правосудия, наконец преступник и правосудие тоже вполне сочетаются, но никак не в плане жертвы.

Советов по правке не даю, ибо всё зависит от контекста. Что там за ситуация-то?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, нет, неправильно. Если он преступник, то уже не может быть именно жертвой правосудия. Лучше тогда сказать "человек стал жертвой правосудия".